# jsf2 after login back to app old user data is shown

Tags: jsf-2.2, managed-bean

I have a session bean like this to store user and logout method:

```
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named("complexBean")
@SessionScoped
public class ComplexBean implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private DirectDAO directDAO;

    private static User loggedUser;

    public String init() {
        if (loggedUser != null) {
            return "";
        } else {
            return "login.xhtml";
        }
    }

    public User getLoggedUser() {
        if (loggedUser == null) {
            loggedUser = directDAO.getLoggerUser();
            logger.error("getting user from DB");
        }
        return loggedUser;
    }

    public String logout() {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
        return "/secure/dashboard?faces-redirect=true";
    }
}
```

method `init()` is invoked on main page, and if user is null, it redirects to login page.
when I login user, it works like charm. When I logout user it works as well - user is always redirected to login page.

Problem is when I login user, then use `logout()` method, and login different user again - in that scenario previous user is being shown.
Plus logs are strange:
[image]

first login is OK - user is being logged in, and data are requested from DB.
When second user logs in there is no request to DB

Comment: .. and it used to work with JSF 1.x?

Comment: no - I am just working on it.

Comment: Then your title and tags are wrong. Then, why is `loggedUser` static?

Comment: a.) why tags are bad?
b.) just found that static user crap while doing code review. cons of working with interns.... question to delete

Comment: loggedUser is part of SessionBean scope, and method logout() does invalidate session. Hence after removing idiotic 'static' everything went back to normal

Comment: Sorry, I read wrong... Cheers... Great it works!